# How to unsubscribe this lambda event?

Tags: c#, events, lambda, cefsharp

I am trying to unsubscribe this event (for **cefsharp** event):

```
wbPrzegladarka.FrameLoadEnd += async (sender, args) =>
{
  //Wait for the Page to finish loading
  if (args.Frame.IsMain)
  {
    await args.Frame.EvaluateScriptAsync("alert('MainFrame finished loading');");
   }
 };
```

In this case, when page will be loaded again, should be not triggered anymore. I am not sure how to deal it with lambdas.

**EDIT:**

I tried this:

```
EventHandler<FrameLoadEndEventArgs> handlerFrameLoadEnd = async (sender, args) =>
            {
                //Wait for the Page to finish loading
                if (args.Frame.IsMain)
                {
                    await args.Frame.EvaluateScriptAsync("alert('MainFrame finished loading');");
                }
            };
            wbPrzegladarka.FrameLoadEnd += handlerFrameLoadEnd;
```

But the event is not trigerred at all, because of some reason.

**EDIT:**

Also tried *Neil's* function event:

```
wbPrzegladarka.FrameLoadEnd += FrameLoad;
wbPrzegladarka.FrameLoadEnd -= FrameLoad;

void FrameLoad(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    //Wait for the Page to finish loading
    if (args.Frame.IsMain)
    {
        args.Frame.EvaluateScriptAsync("alert('MainFrame finished loading');").Wait();
    }
}
```

But is not trigerred at all, because of some reason :/

Comment: Move the lambda into a function and then subscribe/unsubscribe the delegate in the normal way.

Comment: @bakunet move the unsubscription inside the handler body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My final solution is, when I declare inside the class a field:

```
EventHandler<FrameLoadEndEventArgs> handlerFrameLoadEnd;
```

And unsubscribtion is inside the event:

```
handlerFrameLoadEnd = async (sender, args) =>
{
   //Wait for the Page to finish loading
   if (args.Frame.IsMain)
      await args.Frame.EvaluateScriptAsync("alert('MainFrame finished loading');");
   wbPrzelgadarka.FrameLoadEnd -= handlerFrameLoadEnd;
};
```

Also I need to remember to subscribe it after the event:

```
wbPrzegladarka.FrameLoadEnd += handlerFrameLoadEnd;
```

Answer (score 3):

Move lambda Expression into separate method and Unsubscribe inside the method.

```
//subscribe
wbPrzegladarka.FrameLoadEnd += FrameLoad;


public async void FrameLoad(object sender, FrameLoadEndEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Frame.IsMain)
    {
        await args.Frame.EvaluateScriptAsync("alert('MainFrame finished loading');");
        //Unsubscribe 
        wbPrzegladarka.FrameLoadEnd -= FrameLoad;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Move the lambda into a function and then subscribe/unsubscribe the delegate in the normal way.

```
wbPrzegladarka.FrameLoadEnd += FrameLoad;
wbPrzegladarka.FrameLoadEnd -= FrameLoad;

void FrameLoad(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    //Wait for the Page to finish loading
    if (args.Frame.IsMain)
    {
        args.Frame.EvaluateScriptAsync("alert('MainFrame finished loading');").Wait();
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried, but the event is not trigerred at all, because of some reason. And the lambda works fine.